# Can Find My Mac still persist after erasing the hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, partition, unix, find-my-mac, nvram

I have recently acquired a MacBook Air 2011 off of ebay. In order to avoid second-hand Mac issues relating to iCloud remote shut downs, I have performed the following actions:

- Secure erase (using parted magic), deleted old partition and created a new partition (using gparted).
- Cleared PRAM/NVRAM using keyboard procedure a few times, after HD was already wiped.
- Installed Ubuntu (I will be using Ubuntu, and maybe Windows through VB).

Is there any way that Find My Mac capabilities could have persisted, and would it be able to shut me down if I connect the MacBook to the internet and the seller (or sellers seller) decides to lock the device on iCloud?.

The device does not currently have any type of lock, nor did it have it when I received it, as I was able to plug in a USB and boot parted magic. A quick inquiry: I would be able to tell for sure if the device is FMM locked when I connect to the internet, correct? If FMM capabilities are still in order, the laptop would be tracked/locked (if so was the command), even if it was running Ubuntu?

Comment: good work, but answering this without prof of purchase could result in assisting in crime. So why not ask the previous owner to log in and disable it.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your reply. If it helps at all, I am outside of USA :) The MBA was purchased for a low price from a reseller on ebay, and I am concerned that the resellers seller might at some point in the future lock my machine (as happened to my roommate).

Comment: as I said, if it is a legit purchase just contact them and ask for them to remove the FMM lock. But I can tell you that the token for the FMM is saved in NVRAM.

Comment: The device does not currently have any type of lock, nor did it have it when I received it, as I was able to plug in a USB and boot parted magic. A quick inquiry: I would be able to tell for sure if the device is FMM locked when I connect to the internet, correct? If FMM capabilities are still in order, the laptop would be tracked/locked (if so was the command), even if it was running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to find out who is the owner of the computer as reported to Find my Mac.

In terminal use

```
nvram -p | grep fmm
```

If it is your name there then you are fine.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. My dumb*** deleted the partitions on the MBA as soon as I received it, so I have no way of booting terminal or checking NVRAM info. Unless you can point me in the right direction? Would it be worth it to reinstall OS and check NVRAM in terminal?

Comment: As long you are not connected to Internet (no FMM), you should install the OS and then check the NVRAM token for FMM.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will more than likely follow it. Just to confirm: -the keyboard NVRAM reset method (command+option+p+r) wouldn't have cleared the FMM token? -I understand the NVRAM is a seperate deal from the hard drive (and consequently any OS), but to be sure, the NVRAM on the device wouldn't be altered by the reinstallation of OS. Specifically, it wouldn't "layer" on top of the FMM token, while the original FMM token still being active? Even if I disable/clear it in the terminal?